# How to process dynamically in kafka streams and send to different topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am creating a stream processing app. It should create a kafka stream connection. When a message arrives following are the required things I want to do:

- check the type of message
- process the message by calling a specificTypeProcessing Service
- end it to specific topics that are decided on the basis of the message type

  ```
  public java.util.function.Consumer<KStream<String, String>> process() {
      String topic;
      return input ->
              input.map((key, value) -> {
                  //check type and ask object from factory
                  try {
                      JSONObject msg = Util.getObjectMapper().readValue(value, JSONObject.class);
                      String type = msg.get("type").toString();
                      if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("test")){
                          //processing started
                          msgTypeHandlerFactory
                                  .createInstance(type)
                                  .enrichAndRelay(msg);
                          System.out.println("IN");
                      }
                      else{
                          input.to("notStream");
                          System.out.println("OUT");
                      }

                  } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  return KeyValue.pair(key, value);

              })
              .to("output_topic");

  }
  ```

  The issue with the above code is I'm using map function which grants me the ability to use the .to() function to send the stream.
  What I want is to check every message for type and then process, send to another stream accordingly.
  For this, I should use foreach function which doesn't give me .to() function so I have to create another Kafka Producer to do the job.

Requirement:

1. Each msg should be processed and sent before processing the next msg with the help of stream function and not using another kafka producer
2. If the requirement one is achieved then I should be able to send msg to topics that will be decided dynamically according to type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Each msg should be processed and sent before processing the next msg with the help of stream function and not using another kafka producer

This will happen anyways by default.

> 2. If the requirement one is achieved then I should be able to send msg to topics that will be decided dynamically according to type.

First, to make the step easier where you process events depending on their type, take a look at `branch()`. The `branch()` function lets you provide a fixed number of predicates to route messages into different sub-streams. You can then independently process these sub-streams, e.g. with the `map()` function. Finally, you can then send each sub-stream to a separate topic, with `to()`.

```java
KStream<String, Event>[] branches = events.branch(
    (id, event) -> event.getTransactionValue() >= FRAUD_LIMIT,
    (id, event) -> event.getTransactionValue() < FRAUD_LIMIT);
branches[0].map(...).to(suspiciousTransactionsTopicName);
branches[1].map(...).to(validatedTransactionsTopicName);
```

You can also make truly dynamic routing decisions in the `to()` based on whatever is in the payload of an event. Here, the name of the output topic is derived from event data.

```java
myStream.to(
  (eventId, event, record) -> "topic-prefix-" + event.methodOfYourEventLikeGetTypeName()
);
```

Furthermore, if the dynamic routing decision requires information that is not directly available in an event, one option you have is to dynamically enrich the original event with routing-related information (e.g., by joining the original event stream against a table with routing-related info), and then do the dynamic routing via `to()`.  See https://www.confluent.io/blog/putting-events-in-their-place-with-dynamic-routing/ for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check types, you're essentially `filter`ing those events matching those types.

Therefore, you don't need map or foreach, you'd have better luck with `filter(...).to(topic}`

```scala
    final ObjectMapper mapper = Util.getObjectMapper();
    KStream notTestEvents = input.filter((key, value) -> {
        //check type and ask object from factory
        try {
            JSONObject msg = mapper.readValue(value, JSONObject.class); // You should probably use JSONDeserializer instead, which does this for you
            String type = msg.get("type").toString();
            System.out.println("OUT");
            return !type.equalsIgnoreCase("test");     
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    );
    notTestEvents.to("notStream");
```

The other option is branching

```
KStream<String, String>[] branches = events.branch(
    (k, v) -> { 
       return !mapper
          .readValue(value, JSONObject.class)
          .get("type").toString();
          .equalsIgnoreCase("test")
    },
    (k, v) -> true
);
branches[0].map(...).to("notStream");
branches[1].map(...).to("output_topic");
```

Comment: The filter solves the selecting type issue. But does the map function processes and sends one record at a time to the output stream or it processes all records one by one and then sends all records at once to the output stream? I'll be using this as input_stream->filter by type->.map function->.to() fumction

Comment: Both map and filter functions are one by one. You'd need a groupBy or other aggregate to collect data into larger messages